# Is column order in a table relevant for version control?

Tags: sql, version-control

A version control system compares the scripted definition of a table to the checked in state. So I guess many cvs will see column reordering of a table as a change.
Since tsql does not support to add a new column in the middle of a table and because in a relational DB the ordering should not matter, what are good practices for version control of table definitions if the column-order could change.
Sometimes you could need to redo a drop column in the middle of a table.

Comment: If the order of the columns matter, you are probably doing something unwise.

Comment: If someone tried to reorder the columns in an existing table,I would take him out and shoot him (well, fire him).  This is done only by the incompetent dev who is using select *  instead of the names of the columns in his queries. The order of the columns in the table should never matter and anyone who thinks it should is so incompetent they should not be allowed to touch a database. Seriously. In order to change column order you need to copy the data to another table, drop the existing table, recreate the table and copy the data back in. Now consider doing that to a 2 million record table.

Comment: For version control I currently us Visual Studio and before I can upgrade the DB-schema I have to compare the current schema with the schema it should have according to version control and that is the point I get problems with reordered columns. So it is schema-compare. Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing scripts to setup your database in source control, not trying to have something reverse-engineer those scripts from the state of the database. Column-order then becomes a non-issue.

Specifically, I've seen two schemes that work well. In the first, each database schema update script is given a sequential number, and the database tracks which sequence number is the last applied. In the second, each database schema update script is given a UUID, and the database tracks all UUIDs that have been applied.

I would checkout the book [Refactoring Databases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774515) for more details and examples of how to manage database changes.

Comment: The sequential numbers or GUIDs ar good hints. I don't intend to reverse-engineer the scripts, but I am doing a schema compare to check if the current DB schema matches that in version control. And the schema-compare in visual studio uses reverse-enginieered scripts it seems.

Comment: OK, right. I've always found that problematic. Instead, only update database schemas through a main script that executes the sequential/UUID numbered SQL scripts and store the version information in the database. Then you don't have the problem anymore.